# Mocha test says express result is not json. json validate says it is

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I am using mocha with supertest to validate my simple ai endpoint. it retrieves an array from the database and then add it to an object to make it a json Object. when using postman it tells me the header equals "application/json" and if I validate the object it is also right.

But when I run my npm test command it suddenly tells me there was a problem parsing the json object.  Not too certain why this happens. Any help is much appreciated!

My endpoint

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');

const Level = require('../models/Level');

// @route       GET api/level
// @desc        Get all levels from the level database
// @access      Private
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let levels = await Level.findAll({ raw: true, nest: true });

        levelsAsJson = { levels: levels };

        console.log(levels);

        res.status(200).json(levelsAsJson);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

My postman response:
[image]

[image]

my unit test:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
var sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const request = require('supertest');

const app = require('../../index');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('Levels route', () => {
    // test whether the endpoint will respond with a 200
    context('GET /level', () => {
        it('should return all levels from the levels table.', done => {
            request(app)
                .get('/api/level')
                .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                .expect('Content-type', /json/)
                .expect(200, done);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` in your `router.get` callback.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let levels = await Level.findAll({ raw: true, nest: true });

        levelsAsJson = { levels: levels };

        console.log(levels);

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(200).json(levelsAsJson);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually use that as middleware. but setting it in the router also didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I made a stupid little mistake. The done method should be invoked after the status check.  so  .expect(200, done); becomes  .expect(200, done()); hope it helps anyone in the future getting this error.